# sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory

Tags: python, plugins, pip, easy-install

I'm making my first RPG game and I wanted to check if I could load into Python a `.tmx` map I created in Tiled before I finished programming the game.

I'm using Python 3 and I'm on a Mac. 
I heard that I should first install the plugin `pytmx`. I tried everything! `pip install pytmx`? Didn't work. `sudo easy_install pytmx`? Didn't work! All I got was

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
```

Someone told me I must first find the path directory of my python launcher. How do I find it? And if I do, how do I use it to install `pytmx`?

Comment: do you have `pip` or `easy_install` installed? try writing `pip` and `easy_install` on command line. If not , then install them first.

Comment: Which version of python do you have installed (`python --version`)? If you haven't got `pip` install follow the [instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Answer (score 2):

First make sure [you have read the official Python package installation guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html).

[Then enable pip on your system with get-pip.py command](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#install-pip).

[Create virtualenv for your project](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments) where the installed packages will be placed. Never use `sudo` when installing Python packages.